# Decoding special characters bytes with double back slashes

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

```
x = 'Amazing!! Fantastic coffee and cakes to die for \\xf0\\x9f\\x98\\x80\\xf0\\x9f\\x98\\x80'

y = 'There is a line outside the door for good reason! Everything (and there is plenty) is absolutely excellent. As long as you\\xe2\\x80\\x99re a fan of the best freshly made French baked goods and enjoy an amazing croque monsieur, you\\xe2\\x80\\x99ll be happy here!'
```

How do you decode these strings and store in a flat file to show all emojis and other special characters in csv instead of bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have `x` and `y` as type `str`.

You can do this to decode the strings:

```
x = 'Amazing!! Fantastic coffee and cakes to die for \xf0\x9f\x98\x80\xf0\x9f\x98\x80'
y = 'There is a line outside the door for good reason! Everything (and there is plenty) is absolutely excellent. As long as you\xe2\x80\x99re a fan of the best freshly made French baked goods and enjoy an amazing croque monsieur, you\xe2\x80\x99ll be happy here!'

print(bytearray([ord(c) for c in x]).decode('utf-8'))
print(bytearray([ord(c) for c in y]).decode('utf-8'))
```

Prints:

```
Amazing!! Fantastic coffee and cakes to die for 
There is a line outside the door for good reason! Everything (and there is plenty) is absolutely excellent. As long as you’re a fan of the best freshly made French baked goods and enjoy an amazing croque monsieur, you’ll be happy here!
```

---

EDIT: If you have string with double backlashes, you can use `ast.literal_eval` to decode it:

```
x = 'Amazing!! Fantastic coffee and cakes to die for \\xf0\\x9f\\x98\\x80\\xf0\\x9f\\x98\\x80'
y = 'There is a line outside the door for good reason! Everything (and there is plenty) is absolutely excellent. As long as you\\xe2\\x80\\x99re a fan of the best freshly made French baked goods and enjoy an amazing croque monsieur, you\\xe2\\x80\\x99ll be happy here!'

from ast import literal_eval

print(literal_eval('b"""' + x + '"""').decode('utf-8'))
print(literal_eval('b"""' + y + '"""').decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: I just added formatting to OP. There are double backslashes in original (but without code formatting, SO displayed them as single)

Comment: z = "The space is great: open and stylish.Service, not so much. Soo much 'tude from the kids xf0x9fx99x84. I ordered a shrub which arrived in a highball, w a cylindrical ice cube which took up 90% of the glass. Three little sips of elixir and a $9 ice cube xf0x9fx98x86.Lunch was tasty, but I had expected and hoped for much more here."

Hot to handle such cases?

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks @h4z3